# Exim doesn't want to do DKIM signing correctly

Tags: debian, exim, dkim

I'm using exim 4.82 on Debian sid. I've followed several tutorials on how to configure exim to sign outgoing emails, but it seems like something is not behaving as it should be.

My diagnosis is that `$sender_address_domain` is always set to the hostname of the server (`/etc/hostname`), regardless what the `From:` field is in the email message.

I've defined the following macros in `/etc/exim4/conf.d/transport/00_exim4-config_header`:

```
DKIM_CANON = relaxed
DKIM_DOMAIN = ${sender_address_domain}
DKIM_SELECTOR = dkim
DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY = /etc/exim4/dkim.private.key
```

This current setup signs outgoing emails, but the domain in the DKIM signature is always set to `euvps.rolisoft.net`, regardless of the `From:` field. My best guess is `$sender_address_domain` is set to `euvps.rolisoft.net`, when it should be set to the domain of the email address in the `From:` field.

Because of this, the verification fails with `bad version` message:

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=euvps.rolisoft.net; s=dkim;  // <- d= should be set to whatever is in From
    h=Date:Message-Id:From:Subject:To; bh=...; b=...;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of root@euvps.rolisoft.net designates 188.226.159.108 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=root@euvps.rolisoft.net;
       dkim=neutral (bad version) header.i=@euvps.rolisoft.net;
       dmarc=fail (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=seriesinfos.com
```

Setting `DKIM_DOMAIN` manually to a domain name I'm going to send message from solves this, and the DKIM signature becomes valid. However, I'm using multiple domain names, so it would be best if the `DKIM_DOMAIN` would be automatically set to whatever email I'm sending the message from.

I have not set up custom routers and transports as some tutorials suggest it. (I've done it at some point, but it had the same results, so I removed them.)

Setting `DKIM_DOMAIN` to `${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch*@{/etc/exim4/dkim_senders}}` (with `dkim_senders` properly set-up) will simply not sign the messages, however `dkim_senders` doesn't have `euvps.rolisoft.net` in it, so I'm guessing here `$sender_address` is also set to `euvps.rolisoft.net`, which is why the lack of signing.

I'm not exactly sure how to debug what `$sender_address_domain` is set to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I'm still not sure why isn't `$sender_address` correctly populated, I found a workaround solution to my problem using another variable:

```
DKIM_DOMAIN = ${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}
```

This sets the domain name correctly on the DKIM signature.

To stop signing domains I don't have a key for, I've set up two other macros:

```
DKIM_FILE = /etc/exim4/keys/${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}.pem
DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY = ${if exists{DKIM_FILE}{DKIM_FILE}{0}}
```

These essentially just look for a private key in `/etc/exim4/keys/*domain*.pem` and won't sign if it doesn't exist.

Comment: The $sender_address is set by the *ENVELOPE* sender.  You are trying to sign based on the From Header sender.  As you can see, in your case, they are two different things.  Another possible fix would be to redo your email submission code such that the envelope sender is the same as the From header.  The more alignment you get between envelope and headers, the better things are in general.

Comment: Thanks, although I read "envelope" in the documentation, I did not know they're different. I looked up PHP's `mail()`, and it looks like changing the envelope sender is quite a pain, so I guess I will just continue signing based on the `Form` header. I also overwrite the `Return-Path` header to `bounce@${DKIM_DOMAIN}` in order to pass the DMARC ASPF test.

Comment: Many times, the simplest way to control the envelope header is to stop using mail() and instead do smtp to localhost port 25 using some standard PHP Mail framework.  There's a few of them out there.

Comment: yeah, changing envelope sender n php is complicated, you have to turn off PHP's "safe" mode and add the webserver uid/gid  to the exim priviliedged users list. (after that it's pretty easy)